# Oracle SQL - Dynamic Pivot with grand total

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a requirement to create a query which had dynamic column data and this had to be pivoted as rows. I found a really nice function which does this. The article is here, and the source code is at the bottom: http://technology.amis.nl/2006/05/24/dynamic-sql-pivoting-stealing-antons-thunder/

The additional step that I need is to get the grand totals of the rows and columns. If I take the last example from the above article:

```
select * from table( pivot(  'select * from city_connections' ) )
```

which has the following data:

[image]

He created a view of his query, I did the same. But basically now I would like to have another row and column be added which will give me the total. For example some thing like below:

[image]

If I do a ROLLUP('Row Labels') in my original query and then run the pivot function, then I am getting a last null row. Any suggestions would be great, thank you.

I have managed to get the GRAND TOTAL of the rows as:

```
GROUP BY order_source, ROLLUP (status)
order by case
            when status = 'GRAND TOTAL' THEN 1
            ELSE 2
            END;
```

Struggling to get the grand total in the bottom row. But now I need the grand total column.

Current progress is as below:
[image]

My View is created as follows, simplified, which is giving me the current progress image:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEST1 AS
SELECT NVL(status, 'GRAND TOTAL') AS row_labels
      ,order_source
      ,count(1) Count#
FROM
SOMETABLE
GROUP BY order_source, ROLLUP (status)
order by case
        when status = 'GRAND TOTAL' THEN 2
        ELSE 1
        END;

SELECT * FROM TABLE(
pivot('SELECT * FROM TEST1')
);
```

Working towards to create the query which will also select that missing column.

When I run the below query:

```
SELECT NVL(status, 'GRAND TOTAL') AS row_labels
      ,order_source
      ,count(1) Count#
FROM
SOMETABLE
GROUP BY order_source, ROLLUP (status)
order by case
        when status = 'GRAND TOTAL' THEN 2
        ELSE 1
        END;
```

I get the following result:

[image]

Is there a way to sum up the "Complete", "Order Process error", "Credit check declined" and so on so forth? My Grand Total is working fine which goes in the Row Labels column. I want another Grand Total which will go in the Order_Source column summing as I have described.

Changed the base query further to below:

```
SELECT NVL(status, 'GRAND TOTAL') AS row_labels
      ,NVL(order_source, 'GRAND TOTAL2') AS order_source
      ,count(1) Count#
FROM
SOMETABLE
GROUP BY status, ROLLUP (status), CUBE(order_source)
order by case
            when status = 'GRAND TOTAL' THEN 2
            ELSE 1
            END;
```

And the data is:

[image]

But when I run this in my Pivot function same way, it does not pull the GRAND TOTAL2 as another column like its doing for other rows. The query is:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(
pivot('SELECT * FROM TEST1')
);
```

And the data is below, notice I've lost the Grand Total's row...:
[image]

Comment: Not sure what you question is now - you have the grand totals but they're in the wrong place? (Your 1 and 2 are the wrong way round to put that line last; that will put it first?). Or you're still getting nulls? Can you create an SQL Fiddle with some sample data and the query you currently have?

Comment: Thank you Alex, I have updated with the data and the queries.